# How to combine RewriteRule of index.php and queries rewrite and avoid Server Error 404?

Tags: regex, apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Both RewriteRule's works fine, except when used together.

1.Remove all queries except query `?callback=.*`:

```
# /api?callback=foo       has no rewrite
# /whatever?whatever=foo  has 301 redirect  /whatever
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^?#\ ]*)\?[^\ ]*\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} !/api(/.*)?\?callback=.*
RewriteRule .*$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

2.Rewrite **index.php** queries `api` and `url=$1`:

```
# /api           returns data  index.php?api&url=
# /api/whatever  returns data  index.php?api&url=whatever
RewriteRule ^api(?:/([^/]*))?$ index.php?api&url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Any valid combination to this RewriteRule's on keeping its functionality?

This combination will return Server Error 404 to **/api/?callback=foo**:

```
# Remove all queries except query "callback"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^?#\ ]*)\?[^\ ]*\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} !/api(/.*)?\?callback=.*
RewriteRule .*$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]

# Rewrite index.php queries
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} !/api(/.*)?\?callback=.*
# Server Error 404 on /api/?callback=foo and /api/whatever?callback=foo
RewriteRule ^api(?:/([^/]*))?$ index.php?api&url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} !/api(/.*)?\?callback=.*
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: So what happens when you go to `http://your.domain/index.php?url=api/whatever`?

Comment: @JonLin, no idea why you are pointing on that URL. It removes query with 301 redirects to /index.php, since query is not `?callback=.*`.

Comment: Because that's what the second rule is rewriting to, if you comment out the first rule, then go to `http://your.domain/index.php?url=api/whatever` do you get a 404? Does index.php exist in your document root? If it does, is index.php returning a 404?

Comment: .htaccess and index.php are located in same path. Removing line 8 (second line from bottom) will redirect your mentioned URL to `/index.php` has redirect to `/?callback=foo` to `/`. But all queries must be removed except `!/api(/.*)?\?callback=.*`.

Comment: Do you have something in `/api/` that's handling the callback?

Comment: There are no such a folder or file like `/api`, it is handled by `RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`.

Comment: Then why do you have the condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} !/api(/.*)?\?callback=.*` which makes it so if the request is for `/api`, *don't* route it to index.php?

Comment: The `!` means "doesn't match", so you have the condition: "doesn't match /api" and then right after a rule that says "must match /api"

Comment: get rid of the `!` in your condition, as it is, it doesn't make any sense, (since the conditions says "must not start with /api" and the rule matches "must start with /api", so it will always fail no matter what)

Comment: I just updated my question and clarified the issue.

Comment: I see you **still** have the `!` in your condition, if you refuse to remove it, your rule will continue not to work.

Comment: It does not work without `!` either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable `RewriteRule` for **index.php**, need to add in query rewrite exceptions.

This rules works fine and fixes this issue:

```
# Remove question mark and parameters
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
# Query rewrite exceptions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} !/api(/.*)?\?callback=.*
RewriteRule .*$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]

# index.php query rewrite
RewriteRule ^api(?:/([^/]*))?$ index.php?api&url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have to actually spell it out, after 3 comments asking you to remove the `!` from your condition:

```
# Rewrite index.php queries
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} !/api(/.*)?\?callback=.*
# Server Error 404 on /api/?callback=foo and /api/whatever?callback=foo
RewriteRule ^api(?:/([^/]*))?$ index.php?api&url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is the rule that you have that apparently tries to handle the `/api` requests, and this is what is happening:

1. You request `/api?callback=foo`
2. Check against condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} !/api(/.*)?\?callback=.*`
3. Doesn't match because `/api?callback=foo` doesn't match `!/api(/.*)?\?callback=.*`. The `!` says **"the URI MUST NOT BE /api`**
4. Rule ends, nothing happens because condition fails

Another example

1. You request `/blah/`
2. Check against condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} !/api(/.*)?\?callback=.*`
3. Condition matches because `/blah` is not `/api?callback=`
4. Try to apply rule `RewriteRule ^api(?:/([^/]*))?$ index.php?api&url=$1 [QSA,L]`
5. Rule fails because the regex says: **the URI MUST START WITH /api**, since URI is `/blah`, rule doesn't get applied, nothing happens.

So as you can see, no matter what, your rule will never do anything, ever. You need to change your condition so that it doesn't negate the `/api`, because **YOU WANT the /api, it's the whole point of the rule to begin with**. Just match against the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} callback=
RewriteRule ^api(?:/([^/]*))?$ index.php?api&url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Simply removing the `!` is good enough, but it's redundant because you're matching against `/api` in the rule anyways:

```
# This works too
# Look! no more ! here -------------------v
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} /api(/.*)?\?callback=.*
RewriteRule ^api(?:/([^/]*))?$ index.php?api&url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Both your RewriteRule's returns **Server Error 404** on accessing `/whatever`

Comment: @Binyamin neither of them are supposed to handle `/whatever`, you've already got a rule for that, this is specifically to handle `/api`. It's supposed to replace the excerpt that I've taken out of the htaccess that you've posted in your question.

Comment: What I am saying - either `/api` will return **Server Error 404**. Your RewriteRule's does not work.